# Defining numpy.array in the __init__ function of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am not very familiar with writing **classes** in python, I am trying to modify one written class for my application. the problem is that I want to give `halo_pos` parameter as an input to the following `NFW` class:

```
class NFW(object):
    _req_params = { 'mass' : float , 'conc' : float , 'redshift' : float }
    _opt_params = { 'halo_pos' :[float,float]  , 'omega_m' : float , 'omega_lam' : float }
    _single_params = []
    _takes_rng = False
    _takes_logger = False

    def __init__(self, mass, conc, redshift, halo_pos, 
                 omega_m=None, omega_lam=None, cosmo=None):
        self.M = float(mass)
        self.c = float(conc)
        self.z = float(redshift)
        self.halo_pos.x = float(halo_pos[0])
        self.halo_pos.y = float(halo_pos[1])  
        self.cosmo = cosmo
```

if I pass the input for `halo_pos` for the following parameters

```
>>> Xpos.value
array(235.0)
>>> type(Xpos.value)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> Ypos.value
array(340.0)
omega_matter=0.23;omega_lambda=0.77
```

then when I try to call NFW class with the given inputs I get the following error message:

```
nfw = nfw_halo.NFWHalo(mass=M,conc=concentration,redshift=z_halo,halo_pos=[Xpos,Ypos],omega_m=omega_matter,omega_lam=omega_lambda)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "nfw_halo.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.halo_pos.x = float(halo_pos[0])
AttributeError: 'NFWHalo' object has no attribute 'halo_pos'
```

How should I define **halo_pos** for my class in order to avoid raise error message?

Comment: Could you give us a MWE?

Comment: @andi Most new users aren't going to have a clue what a MWE is. Avoid acronyms when posting with new users.

Comment: Sorry, I am new myself and saw that everyone used it. I will avoid that in future. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @andi why doesn't class raise error message for **mass** or **conc** parameters?

Comment: Because for pos.x and pos.y you expect a type that has an x and a y component that can be adressed by ".". How should python know what you are about to creatE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not declaring the halo_pos variable that you're assigning in your **init** section.

```
class NFW(object):
    _req_params = { 'mass' : float , 'conc' : float , 'redshift' : float }
    _opt_params = { 'halo_pos' :[float,float]  , 'omega_m' : float , 'omega_lam' : float }
    _single_params = []
    _takes_rng = False
    _takes_logger = False
    halo_pos = None

    def __init__(self, mass, conc, redshift, halo_pos, 
                 omega_m=None, omega_lam=None, cosmo=None):
        self.M = float(mass)
        self.c = float(conc)
        self.z = float(redshift)
        self.halo_pos = halo_positions(halo_pos)
        self.cosmo = cosmo

        print(str(self.halo_pos.x),str(self.halo_pos.y))

class halo_positions(object):
    x = None
    y = None
    def __init__(self,positions):
        self.x = positions[0]
        self.y = positions[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nfw = NFW(mass=1.23,conc=2.34,redshift=3.45,halo_pos=[4.56,5.67],omega_m=1.111,omega_lam=1.222)
```

so your delclaration self.halo_pos.x and self.halo_pos.y are cleaned up once **init** finishes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice earlier, the .x and the .y might be the problem. Have you created a halo_pos class as well? If not, then you would have to use something else in your variable names instead of the '.'. I've updated my example to show you.

Comment: You should change `halo_pos.x = None` and `halo_pos.y = None` to `halo_pos = None` then he can define `halo_pos` as any object he wants, even if he needs he could use `halo_pos.x` and `halo_pos.y` if defined accordingly.

Comment: @Zifendale what is the difference between these two declarations. I have changed according what you suggested but I get again similar error message `  File "nfw_halo.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.c = float(conc)
AttributeError: 'NFWHalo' object has no attribute 'halo_pos'.
`

Comment: Is the way I defined `halo_pos` in `_opt_params ` fine, when each component of `halo_pos` is an numpy array?

Comment: @Dalek andi's answer is probably the best suggestion. The halo_pos object is not being defined for the class as I have noted. If you define it properly to so that it has .x and .y attributes then that should work. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Zifendale where should I define `self.halo_pos.x ` and `self.halo_pos.y` later? Because it raises an error if I don't and how should they be defined?

Comment: @Dalek I've updated my answer so that it contains a halo_positions class that defines the x and y attributes. I'm sure there is a numpy equivalent of this point class but I don't know it off hand.

Comment: @Zifendale, I have a ridiculous problem, if I write the code line by line it works perfectly but in a script, I am getting the same error message `AttributeError: 'NFW' object has no attribute 'halo_pos'. I can not guess why it is happening!
`

Comment: What line are you getting the AttributeError at? Have you defined halo_pos = None in the first part of the NFW class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55082/discussion-between-zifendale-and-dalek).